# What have I done to VIM?

Tags: vim, ide, macvim

I am trying to figure out what I have done to this source file in VIM (Mac VIM).  I was attempting to use the `>` keyboard shortcut to intent the selected block of code and have obviously done something else to the file.  It *only* effects the text I had selected (both in terms of the named file and position).

To clear the lines I tried:

- Closing and reopening the file
- Cutting the effected text out, saving / closing the file, pasting content back in etc..
- Recreating the file and reopening it in Vim (tabbed session)

While exiting vim and reopening the application cleared the lines, I would still like to know what I had done (to avoid having to close out all of my tabs in the future).

[image: strange lines in VIM]

`:verbose map >` output:

```
n  >p          * :call <SNR>100_putline(']p')<CR>>']
        Last set from ~/.vim/janus/vim/tools/unimpaired/plugin/unimpaired.vim
n  >P          * :call <SNR>100_putline('[p')<CR>>']
        Last set from ~/.vim/janus/vim/tools/unimpaired/plugin/unimpaired.vim
```

Comment: please report the output of `:verbose map >`

Comment: @kent Check out the edit, it's likely not going to show the failure as I closed vim and it went away after that.

Comment: it looks good. because there is no `v` mode mapping for `>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out which syntax group causes the highlighting. `:syn list` shows all active groups, but it's easier when you install the [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin. When you have the name of the offending syntax group, you can investigate where it comes from; (the last lines of) `:scriptnames` may help.

Comment: That makes sense, I will look into installing SyntaxAttr so I have that available next time I confuse myself.